# How to turn on editing in cell Swift 3

Tags: swift, variables, row, cell, editing

I have a question about cell in swift. Let's imagine that I have a cell with 20 rows. The cell is selectable right now, but the thing I want is that, when user selects 20 row it should be editable. And the value which enters the user should be saved in some variable. Is it somehow possible? Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want 20 cells in tableView, then 
You have to make nib of a cell, and make textfield in cell, and also create outlet in nib, (you can also create prototype cell)

Then in `cellForRow AtIndexPath` makes textField delegate as self (to class), in that class you have to implement textField delegate, and then you can access textFields as:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableView(tableView cellForRowAt: IndexPath) as! MYCELL
let text = cell.textField.text
```

Sorry for my bad english,

I think it will be helpful